# AsyncTask unfortunately stops on second execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask, arduino

I'm trying to get strings from my Arduino with my Android phone, everything goes well except for when I press my updatebutton the second time, it unfortunately stops.

I can't seem to track the problem and I ran out of options so I'm asking for help to you guys now.

```
package com.TRY.udp2;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String rcvStr, serverIP="192.168.0.15";
private TextView textLog;//Log for outputs
private EditText textMsg;
Button updateButton;//(dis)connect Button
Boolean connected=false;//stores the connectionstatus
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;//outputstream to send commands
Socket socket = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
    textMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textMsg);
    textLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLog);


    updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            String textlogMsg = textMsg.getText().toString();
            new synchTask().execute(textlogMsg);
        }
    });
}

private class synchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String msg=params[0].toString();
            InetAddress toAddress = null;
            try 
            {
                toAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
            } 
            catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int port=5000;
            DatagramSocket dtSocket = null;

            try 
            {
                dtSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            } 
            catch (SocketException e1) 
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] dataBytes = msg.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sndPacket = new DatagramPacket(dataBytes, dataBytes.length, toAddress, port);
                try 
                {
                    dtSocket.send(sndPacket);
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                try
                {
                    byte[] rcvData = new byte[1024];
                    DatagramPacket rcvPacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvData, rcvData.length);
                    dtSocket.receive(rcvPacket);
                    rcvStr = new String(rcvPacket.getData());
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return rcvStr;
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textLog.setText(rcvStr);
    }

    }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and if there's a better way of getting strings from arduino please help out.

Comment: Does it crash? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: in the console?nothing prints. ,I don't get.

Comment: Stack traces appear in the LogCat, which is different from the normal console. It's always the first place to look for a hint when something goes wrong. But after looking more closely at your code I think I have identified a problem. I posted it as a response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to close `dtSocket` at the end of `doInBackground()`. Otherwise you will try to create a socket on a bound port when you execute it the second time.